A hyperlink in an RDL file works when accessed through a remote browser, but it does not open when a user tries to run it on a local Chrome browser
="javascript:void(renderFunc( '" + Fields!MaterialCode.Value + "' , '" + Fields!MaterialName.Value + "' ))"
The hyperlink in the RDL file, defined as ="javascript:void(renderFunc( '" + Fields!MaterialCode.Value + "' , '" + Fields!MaterialName.Value + "' ))", is not functioning as expected when clicked on a local Chrome browser. Specifically, when a user clicks on the hyperlink, it does not invoke the renderFunc function, which is supposed to be triggered by the hyperlink click event. However, this issue does not occur when the same RDL file is accessed through a remote browser, where the hyperlink click successfully invokes the renderFunc function.
I have tried it on different browsers to check whether it's working or not, but it still didn't work on any local browser. I have used drillthrough instead of hyperlink, but it didn't work either. I invoked that function manually from the console as well as through a button event, and it is invoking that function. However, it is not invoking the function when a user clicks on that hyperlink.
What I want is for the function to be invoked when a user clicks on that hyperlink
